# Google Analytics showing more InApps Events than real ones (Android)

Tags: android, google-analytics, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x

I am developing an Android App.
I fire a Google Analytics event when a purchase has been made successfully.
If I compare the Google Play Developer console data with the Google Analytics data, I see a huge difference between them. I mean there are like 40 or 50 events related to successful purchases (for a lot of different type of items), and in the Google play console I don't see them (only 2 or 3 items).

- Do you know if the same Google Analytics event can be fired multiple times ?
- Is there any possibility my Java code calls the callback function
  OnSuccess function of a purchase multiple times (i am using SDKBOX
  plugin for cocos2d-x), when a purchase is made?

Notice that I see GA events for items that I have never sold.

Many thanks

My last doubt is the apps that hacks for in-app purchases are sufficiently popular that they could be the reason...

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe sdkbox is sending inapp events by itself?

Comment: I think that is not possible, since the event i collect is launched inside the OnSuccesmethod that is only launched when a purchase is completed successfully (there is no integration or similar between SDKBOX and Inapps)

Comment: In firebase analytics it's reported automatically so I thought it may be the case here.

Comment: what do you mean??

Comment: I see Google Analytics boughts of products i have never seen in my developer console

Comment: I mean when you implement firebase analytics (just initialize sdk) it automatically traces events like purchasing in-app product. That wasn't the case in Google Analytics, but maybe something changed.

Comment: Is not the case, I started to receive the events since friday that I integrated GA sdk

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure and its just a guess. May be your users are using some illegal means to buy in-apps like root or jailbreak.